# VBA Runtime error 1004 when exporting data as CSV File

Tags: excel, vba, csv, export

I am trying to export a single sheet to a new CSV file, when I run the macro it works perfectly. But, when I share the file to my colleagues, the export to csv macro throws "Run Time Error 1004" - You cant paste this here because copy area and paste area aren't the same size. Select just one cell in the paste area or an area that's the same size, and try pasting again."

```
Sub ExportToCSV()

    Dim mypath As String, myfilename As String

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook

    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    'Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select cell ranges with changes:", "Cells to be copied", Default:="Select Cell Range", Type:=8)

    'lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Range("A2:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)

    rng.Copy

    Set wb2 = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)

    wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial 'xlPasteValues

    myfilename = "Wave - " & Format(Now, "ddmmmmyyyy")

    fullpath = wb.Path & "\" & myfilename

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    If MsgBox("Data Copied to " & wb.Path & "\" & myfilename & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _

        "Warning:  Files in directory with same name will be overwritten!!", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then

        Exit Sub

    End If

    If Not Right(myfilename, 4) = ".csv" Then myfilename = myfilename & ".cdv"

    With wb2

        .SaveAs Filename:=fullpath, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False

        .Close False

    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Does the original sheet have data past column C?

Comment: In original sheet, data is been imported from another CSV file through Columns A:C.

Comment: Then you can just copy the entire sheet - `ActiveSheet.Copy` - without a destination, and that creates a new workbook which is the `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: I dont want the buttons to be exported. On row 1 of original sheet, I have couple of button to run some specific task.

Comment: One option is to delete them in the new workbook.

Comment: Are they shapes or form controls or what? Those won't get saved in a CSV anyway...

Comment: I have inserted shapes and then assigned macros.